# Query yum database for package availability

Tags: python, bash, yum, repository

I am working on consolidating a set of RPM packages into a new, more organized set of Yum repositories. I have already repackaged a subset of them by hand and uploaded them into the repositories, but I have a much larger set that either build and package automatically, or have newer versions that are available from third party sources.

**I need to be able to, given a package name (and optionally, a list of repository ids), programmatically check and see if it is already available**, and if not, upload it into the repository. I have played around with repoquery and yum search, but neither seem sufficiently scriptable for my purposes.

Comment: What is an example of something you can't do with `yum search`?

Comment: Well let's say I have a package `lighttpd-1.4-6.javanix.i686` locally but I would like to know if I should put it in my new repository. If I  do `yum search lighttpd` I get a bunch of cruft in the output. Is there a way to pare down and nicely format the output of `yum search` so that I can use it in a script without fighting too much? My end result needs to be a python or bash function that returns 0/1 or True/False on whether or not a package is available from one of a set of repositories.

Comment: How about `yum list | grep '^lighttpd\.'`

Comment: I wrote this up, but it focuses on local availability and, as well as the repo being local. Are they going to be stored on different machines. Also when you say repo ids, do you mean the id in the actual .repo file?

Comment: Forgot the [link to the code](http://pastebin.com/etVUbfKE)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement for one of my scripts.   I use the repoquery command to check and see if a particular package/version exists in the remote repository.

Using the below command, you can easily see if a particular package (and all it's versions) exist.

```
repoquery --repoid=<myrepository_id> --qf="package|%{name}|%{version}|%{release}|%{arch}" <packagename_of_interest>
```